# Solution Explorer not showing xna game contents properly in csharp in vs 2010

Tags: visual-studio, xna, solution-explorer

I am developing a game in vs 2010 csharp xna.
Suddenly my game content folder(bagchalGameContent) appears with exclamation signs and the images files inside it cannot be browsed. I have attached image for the same.

Please suggest me the appropriate solution.[image: snapshot]

Comment: Have you deleted any folders recently? Modified the solution? What does the tooltip for this problem say? Generally - what has been changed since it worked?

Comment: yeah i had added some classes and sound files and deleted. But even when i opened the solution from my backup folder it didn't work. Before i was using evaluation version and i provided the activation key searching from google.

Comment: Well, since I don't know what you deleted or moved, the best I could suggest is that you simply create a new XNA Game solution, and just add all your files into it again. Btw, use Visual Studio Express editions rather than pirate ones - these are free **and** legal.

Comment: i created new project and copied the code. It worked. Thanks @Niko Drašković

Comment: No problem, answer your own question (specify what you did), then mark that as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created another project and copied the code, imported all images files. It now worked nicely.

Comment: Thanks i followed your solution. It saved my day.